# How to change Follow Path Speed

Tags: path

I've got a simple object following a bezier circle, and I just want to figure out how to change the speed of the object following the path.  Could somebody show me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking about moving the object the full length of the path at a slower pace, read on...  If you're trying to vary, stop, or even make the object go backwards and forwards, that's a bit more complicated but can be added to explain this.  Just ask.

For the full path length at a slower pace -

Go into the path's properties (at right) and set the "Frames" value to twice what you had before.  Make sure your animation frame range is large enough to accomodate that number of frames.

In the Evaluation slot it's a good idea to delete the maximum frame number you have there already.  (set the timeline cursor to that frame number, hover over the slot and press ALT-i)

Now set the timeline cursor to the same frame number as you entered into the "Frames" slot.

Enter that number into the Evaluation slot and hover over it with the mouse and press i to keyframe it.

You've then doubled the number of frames (time) that your object has to complete the journey.

Comment: hey, thx!  I was trying to make the object go faster, actually, but it's still applicable, of course.  I had been able to do this once, but I forgot how.  One thing I'm wondering about:  What exactly does the maximum frame number do?  I'm not sure what you are doing by deleting a certain keyframe and adding another one at the end.  Could you fill me in?

Comment: Adding the new KF at the (new) end frame number is to provide a new (larger frame range the object has with in which to travel. (slows it down)  Deleting the old KF is just housekeeping.  In theory it shouldn't have any effect, but Blender teaches one to always expect surprises!  Follow the doctors' code - 'When in doubt, cut it out'

Comment: The max frame number?  I'm using 2.77a here and cannot see that one.  All I have is "Frames" (Number of contiguous frames the path will be active for)  e.g. that figure could be 100  frames but the path may not be started until frame 250 and ending at 349

Comment: oh, oops.  I meant the Evaluation Slot.

Comment: An eval'n slot keyframe determines where the object is going to be at a certain frame number.  Setup a path with just the starting and ending keyframes.  Drag the timeline along about half way, then slide the Eval'n slot value and watch what happens.  If you slide it to where you want the object to be at that frame, then keyframe it, that's where it will end up at that frame number when animated.  You can make the object run backwards and forwards this way, even stop there for a while if need be, continue on again later, so long as your frames slot has given it enough frames to do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, @Edgel3D!  I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem.  I have a computer chockers with my old projects because after a while you forget the fine detail.  With Blender it's the fine detail that counts! Sometimes I can't even work out how I managed to get the result I did - i.e. I'm not able to repeat it.  Fluke perhaps?

Comment: Probably not a fluke... with Blender, you can easily miss something.  Seeing we are not the developers of Blender, we don't know or see everything. :D

Comment: If you'd like, through some of those flukes towards me, and I'll see if I know the answer. :)

Comment: There is one that I must get onto - It needs rewriting. We should set up a chat forum or whatever as this wouldn't be the place to discuss that...

Comment: how 'bout you add it as a question?  Or is it the type of question that would be closed? (irritating).

Comment: Can't chit-chat here. We have to set up a chat forum or similar.  I'm trying to do that but can't see how now.  I'm sure I've seen a button for that somewhere.  Thanks to your prompt - re: the problem with an older post, I went into that last night and found the reason it wouldn't work for me.  :)

Comment: Found that button. It's hiding down at the bottom.  If you want to chat, go down to the blue section at bottom left, 3rd option.